# How to pass props to Layout Routes in react-router-dom 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I couldn't find in official React Router Documentation how to pass props from nested routes to Layout route (page). Instead of `<Routes>` I am using `useRoutes` hook.

As you can see from provided code, I want to provide props (image id and title) from children routes (Login, InvestorRegister, ServiceProviderRegister, ForgotPassword, ResetPassword)  to layout route wrapper page (LeftImageLayout).

How to do that? Any suggestions or code improvment will be appreciated. Thank you

I know that I can use `ContextApi` to pass props from parent to child, but I can't do that in my case.

**Layout**

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

const Wrapper = styled("div")({
  backgroundSize: "cover",
  backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
  minHeight: "100vh",
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  justifyContent: "space-between",
});

const LeftImageLayout = ({ image, text }) => {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={0} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
        <Wrapper
          sx={{
            background: `url("https://picsum.photos/1280/957?random=${image}")`,
          }}
        >
          <Typography
            variant="h1"
            sx={{ alignSelf: "flex-start", paddingLeft: 2, paddingTop: 2 }}
          >
            BuildUp
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h2" sx={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
            {text}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="span" />
        </Wrapper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
        <Outlet />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default LeftImageLayout;
```

**Routes**

```
export default function Router() {
  return useRoutes([
    ...
    {
      element: <LeftImageLayout />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/login",
          element: <Login text="Text for login page" image="4" />,
        },
        {
          path: "/investor-registration",
          element: <InvestorRegister text="Text for investor page" image="5" />,
        },
        {
          path: "/service-provider-registration",
          element: (
            <ServiceProviderRegister
              text="Text for service provider page"
              image="6"
            />
          ),
        },
        {
          path: "/forgot-password",
          element: (
            <ForgotPassword text="Text for forgot password page" image="6" />
          ),
        },
        {
          path: "/reset-password",
          element: (
            <ResetPassword text="Text for reset password page" image="7" />
          ),
        },
      ],
    },
    ...
  ]);
}
```

**Login**

```
const Login = () => {
  return ( // Place for React hook form );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use `window.location.pathname` to conditionally render content (image id and text), like this:

```
const LeftImageLayout = () => {
  const pathName = window.location.pathname.substring(1);

  let image = "";
  let text = "";

  switch (pathName) {
    case "login":
      text = "Hundreds of on-demand workers are open to work!";
      image = "1";
      break;
    case "investor-registration":
      text =
        "Access the selection of hundreds construction related on demand workers, ready to work with you.";
      image = "2";
      break;
    case "service-provider-registration":
      text =
        "Offer your services to a various investors looking for talented construction related people like you.";
      image = "3";
      break;
    case "forgot-password":
      text =
        "We help talents in construction related services connect with local investors.";
      image = "4";
      break;
    case "reset-password":
      text =
        "Talents and experienced investors combined to bring extraordinary results.";
      image = "5";
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={0} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
        <Wrapper
          sx={{
            background: `url("https://picsum.photos/1280/957?random=${image}")`,
          }}
        >
          <Typography
            variant="h1"
            sx={{ alignSelf: "flex-start", paddingLeft: 2, paddingTop: 2 }}
          >
            BuildUp
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h2" sx={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
            {text}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="span" />
        </Wrapper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
        <Outlet context={{ image, text }} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Instead of `window.location.pathname` we can use hook `useLocation()`

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue and use `<Route handle>`

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <DefaultLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        element: <Root />,
        handle: { // <== HERE
          layout: {
            title: "Home page title",
          },
        },
      },
      {
        path: "about",
        element: <About />,
        handle: { // <== HERE
          layout: {
            title: "About page title",
            contained: true,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const DefaultLayout = () => {
  const layout = useDefaultLayout();

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(layout, null, 2)}</pre>
      <hr />
      <main>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
export function useDefaultLayout() {
  const match = useMatch();
  const contained = Boolean(match?.handle?.layout?.contained);

  return {
    title: match?.handle?.layout?.title,
    contained,
  };
}

export function useMatch() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const matches = useMatches();

  return [...matches.reverse()].find(
    (match) => match.pathname === location.pathname
  );
}
```

Full example [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/condescending-bush-wy2yzc?selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A15%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A5%7D%5D&file=%2Fsrc%2Flib%2Froute.ts&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522clazqgcw303aa3b6i4in51g52%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252Fsrc%252Frouter.tsx%2522%252C%2522%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Froute.ts%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522clazq3k4g000n3b6ipux557wu%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clazq3k4g000n3b6ipux557wu%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2520Space%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clazq3k4h000o3b6ibhh6l6y9%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Fabout%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522clazq3k4g000n3b6ipux557wu%2522%257D)

Comment: nitpick: `return matches.findLast((match) => match.pathname === location.pathname);` is a bit more efficient and readable. Thanks for the snippets

Answer (score 0):

You could use `useState` hook. In **Routes**, you'd need to add this code:

```
const [image, setImage] = useState('')
const [text, setText] = useState('')
```

I'm not sure if you need to both set and display image and text in your children components. To make your life a little bit easier, you'd probably want to put that state into an object that you'd pass as a prop:

```
const params = {
  image,
  setImage,
  text,
  setText
}
```

This would be an example entry in your `children` array:

```
{
  path: "/login",
  element: <Login params={params} />,
}
```

In `Login` component, you'd add the following:

```
const Login = ({ params }) => {
  const { setImage, setText } = params
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setText('Text for login page')
    setImage('4')
  }, [])
  
  //...
}
```

`LeftImageLayout` would take `params` as a prop, as well, the diference being that you'd access `text` and `image` values when deconstructing `params`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what do you think about `useParams` from react-router-dom. Maybe it's also good idea to conditionally render content (image and text) ?

Comment: You'd probably need to use [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) in your case. Conditional rendering sounds like a good idea. If you provide invalid path params, fallback to some default value.

Comment: see my answer below. What do you think ?

Comment: I think it's okay. I assumed that your children components need to get `image` and `text` props. If not, your solution is most probably the way to go.